# How to send Javascript/jQuery array over URL paramter to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

Here's my script, this works fine... `send_array_to_other_page.html`

```
$(function(){
    //DECLARE ARRAY
    var arr = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#box').val();
        var index = arr.length;
        var list = ''; 
        //ADD VALUE TO ARRAY
        arr[index] = value; 
        //OUTPUT VALUES IN ARRAY
        for (var index in arr){
            list+=index+': '+arr[index]+'<br/>';
            $('#arrLength').html(arr.length);
        }
        //DISPLAY ARRAY
        $('#display').html(list);
        $('#form').get(0).reset(); //RESET FORM
    });
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        window.location = 'send_array_to_other_page_2.php?list='+arr;
    });
});
```

This doesn't. It outputs `Array content lost`. Id also like to point out the the url of this page is `send_array_to_other_page_2.php`. Its missing the `?list=`

```
<?php
    $arr = $_GET['list'];
    echo 'The contents of the array are still... <br/>';
    if(isset($arr)){
        print_r($arr);
    } else {
        echo 'Array content lost';
    }
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you do $arr = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]

Comment: I tried $arr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], it did not display 'Array content lost' but it also did not output the content of the array, only blank.

Comment: What if you do a var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);

Comment: Tried it, it displays as a string not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    //DECLARE ARRAY
    arr = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#box').val();
        var index = arr.length;
        var list = ''; 
        //ADD VALUE TO ARRAY
        arr[index] = value; 
        //OUTPUT VALUES IN ARRAY
        for (var index in arr){
            list+=index+': '+arr[index]+'<br/>';
            $('#arrLength').html(arr.length);
        }
        //DISPLAY ARRAY
        $('#display').html(list);
        $('#form').get(0).reset(); //RESET FORM
    });
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        window.location = 'send_array_to_other_page_2.php?list='+arr;
    });
});
```

Try without the var arr to make it global, I don't believe the sub functions are parsing it.

Comment: It works now, the content is being displayed in PHP but as a string not an array. I tried this foreach( $arr as $index => $value){
echo 'Index '.$index.' has value '.$value;
} and Im getting an error that the for each() has an invalid argument

Comment: Because $arr will only be a string.  If you're doing .php?list='foobar' and you're asking for $_GET['list'] then you've already stated what the index is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't sent 'long' data over a URL. Most browsers have a length limit and it's very easy to exceed that and end up with corrupted data. For 'big' data, use a POST, which is not limited.

To send the array itself, just do an AJAX request and let jquery encode the array into JSON. You then handle it in PHP with `json_decode()` and you'll end up with a native PHP array.

Comment: Hi. Im not too familiar with JSON. The only JSON Im able to do was from PHP to JS and not the other way around. How do I encode a jQuery array to JSON?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery. JSON basically boils down to raw javascript code for defining variables' values. If you have `var x = [1,2,3]`, then the `[1,2,3]` portion is what gets encoded into json format, and would actually look almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Updated the [JavaScript on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h9SJ/2/) based on your comment. On "submit", the array is saved at the "#form" element using the [.data()](http://jqapi.com/#p=data) method. On "click" of the "#submit" button, that data is retrieved and the url is build up.

---

The click event does fire before the submit event (at least in my Firefox 7), so your array is empty when concatenated to the URL string.

I put together [some JavaScript on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h9SJ/1/) that might help. You do not really need to bind to the click event of the submit-button, just do the "redirect" in the submit handler function. You are building your string `list` there anyways. So there would no confusion what fires first, the click or the form submit event.

As for the serialization of your array, I used [jQuery's .each() function](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.each) but there is nothing wrong doing it by hand (if done correctly).

I could also imagine that the form is actually posted and this is why you do not see the "?list" search part of the URL.

If you don't need a complete redirect, why don't you send the data using [jQuery.get()](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.get)?

Comment: Im sorry if it caused any confusion but the $('#submit') is not actually a submit button type. Its only a button with an id 'submit'.  I actually need to redirect to the PHP page.